# Postgres select by array element range

Tags: arrays, regex, postgresql, select

In my table I've got column facebook where I store  facebook data ( comment count, share count etc.) and It's an array. For example:

```
{{total_count,14},{comment_count,0},{comment_plugin_count,0},{share_count,12},{reaction_count,2}}
```

Now I'm trying to SELECT rows that facebook total_count is between 5 and 10. I've tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM pl where regexp_matches(array_to_string(facebook, ' '), '(\d+).*')::numeric[] BETWEEN 5 and 10;
```

But I'm getting an error:

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: numeric[] >= integer

Any ideas?

Comment: total_count is always first?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to convert the array to text and use regexp. You can access a particular element of the array, e.g.:

```
with pl(facebook) as (
values ('{{total_count,14},{comment_count,0},{comment_plugin_count,0},{share_count,12},{reaction_count,2}}'::text[])
)

select facebook[1][2] as total_count
from pl;

 total_count 
-------------
 14
(1 row)
```

Your query may look like this:

```
select *
from pl 
where facebook[1][2]::numeric between 5 and 10
```

---

Update. You could avoid the troubles described in the comments if you would use the word `null` instead of empty strings `''''`.

```
with pl(id, facebook) as (
values 
    (1, '{{total_count,14},{comment_count,0}}'::text[]),
    (2, '{{total_count,null},{comment_count,null}}'::text[]),
    (3, '{{total_count,7},{comment_count,10}}'::text[])
)

select *
from pl 
where facebook[1][2]::numeric between 5 and 10

 id |               facebook               
----+--------------------------------------
  3 | {{total_count,7},{comment_count,10}}
(1 row)
```

However, it would be unfair to leave your problems without an additional comment. The case is suitable as an example for the lecture **How not to use arrays in Postgres**. You have at least a few better options. The most performant and natural is to simply use regular integer columns:

```
create table pl (
    ...
    facebook_total_count integer,
    facebook_comment_count integer, 
    ...
    );
```

If for some reason you need to separate this data from others in the table, create a new secondary table with a foreign key to the main table.

If for some mysterious reason you have to store the data in a single column, use the [`jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html) type, example:

```
with pl(id, facebook) as (
values 
    (1, '{"total_count": 14, "comment_count": 0}'::jsonb),
    (2, '{"total_count": null, "comment_count": null}'::jsonb),
    (3, '{"total_count": 7, "comment_count": 10}'::jsonb)
)

select *
from pl 
where (facebook->>'total_count')::integer between 5 and 10
```

[`hstore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) can be an alternative to `jsonb`.

All these ways are much easier to maintain and much more efficient than your current model. Time to move to the bright side of power.

Comment: I've run the second query and I'm getting an error:
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""

Comment: Ok I've found that there are some rows like this:
{{commentsbox_count,""},{comment_plugin_count,""},{total_count,""},{comment_count,""},{share_count,""},{reaction_count,""}}
and I think this is the problem. Any ideas how to fix it? Exclude those rows from query?

Comment: Ok I've found a solution:
SELECT facebook[1][2] FROM pl WHERE (facebook[1][2] != '') AND (facebook[1][2]::numeric BETWEEN 5 and 10)